# provider hosted Add-ins in SharePoint team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Can we create provider hosted Add-ins in SharePoint team site ?

How to identify Development site and Team site in SharePoint online ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You need to set up development environment before you can create any add-ins.

To answer your question, you cannot create provider hosted add-in but you can consume the add-in in Team site.

While creating a site, you need to select Development site in the site templates available.

Also there are other pre-requisites that need to be done in order to prepare for the development environment.

[setting up Dev environment](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/set-up-an-on-premises-development-environment-for-sharepoint-add-ins)

[Getting Started with provider hosted Add-in](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins)

Should you need more details on any specific part , please reply -shall try best to answer.

Dev Site will look like the image attached , unless its altered.

Comment: how can we identify SharePoint site ? Like development site or Team site or else.

Comment: edited my answer to add images of the Dev Site templates.